# Global transformation information

Tags: 3d-view, transforms

I don't know where to look for global transformation info like rotation angles, xyz relative to the main origin etc. Would be helpful I could see it, any ways to have it on the display?

Answer (score 0):

first select your object (in object mode), then press N and under the "item" tab you find it:

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, you misunderstood my question. In blender there is a global origin around which you rotate everything in the scene when you press the middle mouse button and move the mouse, you also move things relative to it when holding shift + middle mouse button. There should be somewhere numbers about the angle and position of it but it seems like a have to look at the code

Comment: Also I am interested about its location information in relation to where we view the scene from (I can set cameras for it but thought there is a way to to do it without them)